# Access MsgBox for automated email

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba, microsoft-access

I have an Access DB set up with VBA code for a yes/no command button to send an automated Outlook email. If user selects Yes, it opens the email to allow for attachments.

My problem is that when the user selects no, the message does not go away and send the email as prompted but instead asks the question again for a second response prior to sending the email. I've tried placing an "end" in the second half of the code in various places but nothing seems to work. Suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Code below:

```
Private Sub Command2064_Click()

Const cstrPrompt As String = _
    "Do you want to add an attachment to your audit feedback?"
If MsgBox(cstrPrompt, vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then

'******begin code******
Dim olApp As Object
   Dim objMail As Object

   Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") 'See if Outlook is open

   'Create e-mail item
   Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

'***creates and sends email
With objEmail
    With objMail
     .To = Me.Combo0 & "" & "@myemail.com"
     '.Cc = "ccaddress@yourmailaddress.com"
     .Subject = "Audit Correction Needed"
     .Body = Me.Text136 & "          " & "          " & Me.Combo154 & "                    " & Me.Text1677
     .Display
     End With
     End

End With
End If


If MsgBox(cstrPrompt, vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then

  Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application") 'See if Outlook is open
  'Create e-mail item
   Set objMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  '***creates and sends email
With objEmail
    With objMail
     .To = Me.Combo0 & "" & "@myemail.com"
     '.Cc = "ccaddress@yourmailaddress.com"
     .Subject = "Audit Correction Needed"
     .Body = Me.Text136 & "          " & "          " & Me.Combo154 & "                    " & Me.Text1677
     .send
     End With


End With


  MsgBox "Audit Correction Email has been sent. You must now select the Send to Tracking Sheet button."

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered my own question - all I had to do was remove the duplicate code in my second If statement.

**`MsgBox(cstrPrompt, vbQuestion + vbYesNo) =`**